# JavaScript prototype extending

Tags: javascript, variables, prototype, global, extending

I'm trying to extend an Abstract object.

```
var Abstract = function() { code = 'Abstract'; };
Abstract.prototype.getCode = function() { return code; };
Abstract.prototype.getC = function() { return c; };

var ItemA = function() { code = 'ItemA'; c = 'a'; };
ItemA.prototype = Object.create(Abstract.prototype);
ItemA.prototype.constructor = ItemA;

var ItemB = function() { code = 'ItemB'; };
ItemB.prototype = Object.create(Abstract.prototype);
ItemB.prototype.constructor = ItemB;

var b = new ItemB();
console.log(b.getCode());
var a = new ItemA();
console.log(b.getCode());
console.log(b.getC());
```

The result:

```
ItemB
ItemA
a
```

Is there any particular reason why I'm getting ItemA's scope in ItemB instance? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you are using global variables. Fix it by using `this` keyword:

```
var Abstract = function() { this.code = 'Abstract'; };
Abstract.prototype.getCode = function() { return this.code; };
Abstract.prototype.getC = function() { return this.c; };

var ItemA = function() { this.code = 'ItemA'; this.c = 'a'; };
ItemA.prototype = Object.create(Abstract.prototype);
ItemA.prototype.constructor = ItemA;

var ItemB = function() { this.code = 'ItemB'; };
ItemB.prototype = Object.create(Abstract.prototype);
ItemB.prototype.constructor = ItemB;
```

Although in this case `ItemB.getC()` will return undefined.